# What RNG algorithm would be the best (simplicity vs efficiency vs effectiveness) for use in a music player shuffle script?

Tags: algorithm, random

The only requirements are the ones listed - simplicity, efficiency, and effectiveness. Effectiveness defined simply as sufficiently random so as to not be noticeable by the listener.

**NOTE:** I realize stackoverflow gets easily offended by questions that are likely to involve opinionated answers even though simple "How do you do this in [language]?" questions are often full of exactly such answers and is, therefore, likely to get shut down soon enough by some opinionated user, but I'm gonna give it a shot anyway.

I don't know nearly enough about the subject (RNG) to form my own opinion but I can develop code for an algorithm easy enough. All I'm asking is for some help with choosing said algorithm.

Comment: What are you using it for: creating random music? Shuffling playlists? Other?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Shuffling (edited question). Language doesn't matter. I'm not looking for an implementation. I just don't understand the lingo so reading the algorithm descriptions, benefits, and pitfalls is like reading Greek. I don't know Greek.

Comment: "stackoverflow get easily offended ..." We're trying to build an archive of essential questions and answers. As it stands, I doubt this question will be a very good addition to it.

Comment: "essential answers and questions" is itself subjective. What one deems essential the next will deem superfluous. I guess I just don't understand why asking a question like this is so poorly received when a significant portion of answers to very specific questions are themselves opinionated. Why is one any better than the other?

Comment: Actually what offends Stack Overflow the most are people who are openly antagonistic from the start.

Comment: I don’t see that **Sam** has been in _any_ way antagonistic. SO is well-known for having regulars be openly antagonistic to the hoi-polloi, though.

Comment: Just to not leave you empty handed, I'm going to suggest a [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).  They're simple and fast, but don't generate the best randomness - but I suspect that's not your top concern.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I don't see how you can think the text after the big bold NOTE is not antagonistic.

Comment: Read data from the `/dev/urandom`

Comment: Yeah, that’s new to me. Still, I think that is a response, common when people ask a simple question and feel mistreated for it...

Comment: @MarkRansom LCG. Thanks for that. Good enough is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: Closing this question was the right choice. Apologies all for being antogonistic. I should know better. Now I just have to decide whether to delete the question or leave it here for an example of how NOT to ask a question. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick one. It’ll probably do.

<sub>If it doesn’t, swap it for another.</sub>

I don’t know *how* you intend to use random values for music generation, but you will likely have to filter them in some way to get the final sound result you desire.

If you are using it to generate the melody, no RNG will work nicely. Better to work on that kind of stuff yourself, and only use a RNG to select between different options.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. Not using for generation. Just a shuffle script. Wanting to get away from the expensive library calls for RNG. Edited question.

Comment: "Just pick one, it'll probably do" seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Sam why do you think those library calls are expensive?  Do you suppose it's because good random number generators are hard and do a lot of work?  What secret do you hope to find that the library writers don't already know?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Perhaps, but “Which to use?” ⟶ “any will do” is a direct question ⟶ answer relationship. [Comments are not meant to answer questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: @Sam You would be surprised how little code most pseudo-random number generators require. Unless you are statically linking a large library of them without any dead code removal (look for _Link Time Optimization_) it is not an issue.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think they're expensive because in the very tight confinements in my particular case they are expensive. I'm not looking to uncover any secrets or write the next great algorithm. I simply want advice on algorithms that would be appropriate for the use case - specifically, shuffling a music catalog. Mersenne twister? LCG? Is one overkill? Is it not enough? Idk. That's why I'm here.

Comment: @Sam Now see, these are details that are missing from your question. What are the "tight confinements" you are speaking of?

Comment: Agreed here. @Sam, you might want to re-consider how tight your requirements are... If you have space to actually _play_ music, you certainly have space to shuffle. There is an aphorism amongst programmers that goes _premature optimization is the root of all evil_. A bit of a joke, but always spot-on.

Comment: I asked the broad question because I was unsure how to ask a good specific question. The project is a mod for a video game. The modding community makes it quite clear how expensive the library calls for randomInt are so I was going to roll my own to avoid those calls. But in looking into the topic, I found myself confused by the jargon on what algorithm would be a good fit. I just wanted some advice. Apologies for being antagonistic. It's been a day and I should know better than to take it out on a community I rely on so much.

Comment: @Sam Alas, I know nothing about the game mod community. You might want to ask there specfically on Reddit. However, _getting_ a random value is _never_ that expensive. Every extant game has at least one PRNG at its core. It is what you _do_ with it that may be expensive. I suspect you are reading into slow _scripts_ that do something with PRNG value(s).

Comment: @Dúthomhas it's not super expensive, but you'd be surprised.  I certainly was when someone pointed out that an algorithm I'd come up with was limited by the number of random numbers I was asking for.